# how to implement video gallery in android

Tags: android, video

i am developing an app that has a video gallery in it. The gallery has thumbnail view of recent videos. when user clicks the video must be played. the video is coming from server only.

Comment: how do i implent this. i need the tile views of video in grid/list.

Comment: you should try to develop it , and when you have some problems and errors or exceptions ,then you can post a question here and we will help you , :)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are looking to implement [Android CoverFlow](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html) same as youtube video gallery.